# Base of topology and $B_k$ is finer than the standard topology in R

Tags: general-topology

Hello I have problems with this exercise

Let $K= \{ \displaystyle\frac{1}{n} : n \ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq{1}}$. Let the following families of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ be:

$B= \{ (a,b)\subset{\mathbb{R}}: a<b \} $ and $B^{\prime}=\{ (a,b)$\ $ K \subset{\mathbb{R}}: a<b \} $

Prove that $B_K = B \cup{B^{\prime}} $  is a base of a topology and $B_k$ is finer than the standard topology in R

My attempt

(1)

I have to prove that :

Let $X$ be a set and $B ⊂ P(X)$ a family of subsets. There exists a topology on $X$ for which $B$ is a basis if and only if two conditions hold:

1. $X= \cup \{ B| B \in \mathbb{B}$
2. For any pair $A,B \in \mathbb{B} $ and any point $x \in  A \cap B$ there exist $C \ in \mathbb{B}$ such that $x \in C \subset{A\cap{B}}$
3. $\mathbb{B}= \cup \{ B| B \in \mathbb{B}$ (I don't know what argument to use)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need first prove two things:

- $\mathbb R = \bigcup B_K$, in other words, for each $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists $I \in B_K$ (i.e. $I \in B$ or $I \in B'$) such that $x \in I$; and also
- if $I_1$ and $I_2$ are in $B_K$ (that is, you need to consider the cases in which both are in $B$, both are in $B'$, or one is in $B$ while the other is in $B'$) and $x \in I_1 \cap I_2$, then you can find $I \in B_K$ such that $x \in I \subseteq I_1 \cap I_2$.

Finally, you need to prove that if $\tau$ is the topology
$$\tau = \{U \subseteq \mathbb R : (\forall x \in U)(\exists I \in B_K) \ x \in I \subseteq U\}$$ then $\tau$ is finer than the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, in other words, every open set in $\mathbb R$ ("open" in the usual sense, like in analysis) is an element of $\tau$.

Comment: How do I taste this part: If $I_1$ and $I_2$ are in  $B_k$ ...

Comment: You don't need to prove that, you need to pick two arbitrary elements in $B_K$ (for example, one case is starting with $I_1 = (a,b)$ and $I_2 = (c,d) \setminus K$) and then for every $x \in I_1 \cap I_2$ you need to find $I \in B_K$ such that $x \in I \subseteq I_1 \cap I_2$.

Comment: Ok but i can't find  $I \in B_K$ such that $x \in I \subseteq I_1 \cap I_2$